# Python regex that matches any word that contains exactly n digits, but can contain other characters too

Tags: python, regex

e.g. if n=10, then the regex:

Should match:

```
(123)456-7890
(123)456-(7890)
a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k
```

But should not match:

```
(123)456-789
(123)456-(78901)
etc.
```

Note: I'm strictly looking for a regex and that is a hard constraint.

======================================

Edit: Other constraints

I am looking for a solution of the form:

```
regex = re.compile(r'?????????')
```

where:

```
regex.findall(s)
```

... returns a non-empty array for s in ['(123)456-7890','(123)456-(7890)', 'a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k']

and returns an empty array for s in ['(123)456-789', '(123)456-(78901)']

Comment: are numbers always in order? have you made an attempt, can you provide your attempt?

Comment: @depperm the numbers are not always in increasing order. I tried re.compile('\b[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\d[^\s\d]*?\b') but that does not work.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest For example: ccc = re.compile(r'\bccc\b') will not match '(ccc)'. However, ccc.findall('(ccc)') will yield ['ccc']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex `^\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*$` will find all the matches. Changing this to work for `n` digits use `"^"+"\D*\d"*n+"\D*$"`

```
import re

n=10
regex = "^"+"\D*\d"*n+"\D*$"

numbers='''(123)456-7890
(123)456-(7890)
a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k


(123)456-789
(123)456-(78901)'''

matches=re.findall(regex,numbers,re.M)

print(matches)
```

Or for a single match

```
pattern = re.compile("^"+"\D*\d"*n+"\D*$")
print(pattern.match('(123)456-7890').group(0)) #(123)456-7890 or AttributeError if no match so wrap in try except
```

Comment: with nine = re.compile(r"^\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*$"), nine.findall('(123)45-6789') yields the empty array.

Comment: @JamesShapiro yes I made an edit to work for `n` digits, I forgot the question was for n not 10 digits

Comment: This works for strings, but not for words. ten.findall('(123 45-67890)') finds a match, when it should not.

Comment: I think pattern = re.compile("^"+"[^\s\d]*\d"*n+"[^\s\d]*$") does the trick

Answer (score 2):

Simply by replacing all non-digit characters from an input string:

```
import re

def ensure_digits(s, limit=10):
    return len(re.sub(r'\D+', '', s)) == limit

print(ensure_digits('(123)456-(7890)', 10))             # True     
print(ensure_digits('a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k', 10))   # True
print(ensure_digits('(123)456-(78901)', 10))            # False
```

- `\D+` - matches one or more non-digit characters

---

Version for a list of words:

```
def ensure_digits(words_lst, limit=10):
    pat = re.compile(r'\D+')
    return [w for w in words_lst if len(pat.sub('', w)) == limit]

print(ensure_digits(['(123)456-7890','(123)456-(7890)', 'a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k'], 10))
print(ensure_digits(['(123)456-789', '(123)456-(78901)'], 10))
```

prints consecutively:

```
['(123)456-7890', '(123)456-(7890)', 'a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k']
[]
```

Comment: This is not a regex that accomplishes the task. This is a function wrapped around a regex, and your solution doesn't work without invoking the function. See my edit above for more explicit constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting to inject in your pattern the amount of numbers `n` you want. Also, you need to use the flag [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags).

```
import re

txt = """(123)456-7890
(123)456-(7890)
a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k
(123)456-789
(123)456-(78901)"""

n = 10
rgx = re.compile(r"^(?:\D*\d\D*){%d}$" % n, re.MULTILINE)
result = rgx.findall(txt)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
['(123)456-7890', '(123)456-(7890)', 'a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k']
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression might likely validate the 10 digits:

```
^(?:\D*\d|\d\D*){10}\D*$
```

which we can simply replace 10 with an `n` var.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YBEBMe/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/YBEBMe/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
import re

print(re.findall(r"^(?:\D*\d|\d\D*){10}\D*$", "a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k"))
```

#### Output

```
['a1b2c3ddd4e5ff6g7h8i9jj0k']
```

Comment: the actual question is about `n` digits